# How to find 25th of every quarter from current date in year using Automation anywhere tool?

Tags: automationanywhere

How to find 25th of every quarter from current date in year using Automation anywhere tool? Going to modify string accordingly.

Comment: Can you explain more? give us example input and output

Comment: Firstly, what version of Automation Anywhere are you using? V10, V11, 2019? If you are using V11,  there is a metabot on the Bot Store for date/time manipulation. https://botstore.automationanywhere.com/bot/perform-date-time-operations/ Also you don't indicate what type of quarter. Fiscal or Calendar (April vs Jan for first Quarter etc).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the javascript which you can run and store the value in the variable.

```
function getQ25thDate(){
    var today = new Date();
    var quarters = [1,2,3,4];
    var qEndingMonth = quarters[Math.floor(today.getMonth()%3)]*3;
    var date = new Date(today.getFullYear(), qEndingMonth,1); 
    var value = date.getFullYear()  + date.getMonth() + "25"
    return value;
}
```